# Check my find/exec command before running

Tags: 18.04, scripts, ubuntu-mate, find

Before I run this, I want to make sure it is correct.

I want to delete any .deb files.

```
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/expunged/ -type f -exec rm *.deb
```

This works on all files except .deb files.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/expunged/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/files/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/info/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

And it works completely with UM 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

I would do a non-changing test

```
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/expunged/ -name '*.deb' -type f -print
```

If the output lists the deb files you want to delete

```
find /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/expunged/ -name '*.deb' -type f -print -delete
```

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: @fixit7 "It did not work" is __not__ a useful statement.  Explain what, _precisely_, happened when you ran the first (non-changing) command.  How was the result different from what you expected?  Did it show files?  Did it produce an error?  If so, _exactly_ what error did you see?

Comment: It showed no files nor any messages. There has to be a way as emptying the trash always works. @John1024

Comment: If the `find` command showed no files, that means that there were no files under `/home/andy/.local/share/Trash/expunged/` with a name matching the glob `*.deb`.  Did you need a different directory or a different glob?

Answer (score 1):

You got some great answers already!

You can also make your own recycle bin if you are not 100% sure you are deleting the correct files.

Creates a recycle bin folder in your home directory.

```
mkdir ~/my-bin
```

Find files ending in .deb and move them to the my-bin folder.
{} is expanded to the file path of each search result.

```
find your-path-here -name '*.deb' -exec mv '{}' my-bin ';'
```

You can now browse your recycle bin.

```
ls ~/my-bin
```

And empty it when you are sure about your command.

```
rm ~/my-bin/*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm /home/andy/.local/share/Trash/files/*.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`rm -i` option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/rm.1.html#options):

> `-i` prompt before every removal

```sh
find <folder> -type f -exec rm -i "*.deb"
```